# What is the philosophical definition of life?

Tags: life, definitions, philosophy-of-science

How does philosophy define life? And how does it overlap and contrast with the concepts and nuances of other sciences such as biology, chemistry, physics and mathematics?

Comment: There is no scientific definition that differs from the philosophical definition. You should ask your question on philosophy.SE. If you happen to speak french [this book by Bersini](https://www.amazon.ca/comment-d%C3%89finir-vie-lintelligence-artificielle/dp/2711748650/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1489673580&sr=8-1&keywords=comment+definir+la+vie) is a very good overview of the diversity and difficulties of how to define life

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be better suited for philosophy.SE

Comment: But, this question equally fits in the science section. The philosophy section might argue that it belong to the pure Science section. So, I request not to close but give sometime for other to follow. I just want to hear some thoughts, and might close if it doesn't receive as much attention. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nope philosophers will not consider that this is a science question. However, they may consider the question as being too broad such as the post [What are the phylosophical implications of the definitions of life?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40692/what-are-the-phylosophical-implications-of-the-definitions-of-life). You should probably start with [wikipedia > life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life)

Comment: I don't speak french. Hope there is an english version of that book. Also, any personal reviews on that book. I couldn't see any rating or review online. Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b: I have read about several topics on wikipedia, as a matter of fact I am an avid wiki reader. The link to the question you posted is closed and marked as broad. But, on my question I think I pointed out specifically - what overlaps and constraints philosophical concepts of life with material science? Isn't that specific?

Comment: If it is specific, then it is opinion based as it falsely assume that scientists have a clearly defined concept of life and same for philosophers.

Comment: You're asking for *the philosophical* definition of life. How *philosophy* defines life. This is very explicitly not a biology question. The philosophy section might argue it belongs in the science question but I don't know on what basis they would do so when the question is so clearly and explicitly restricted to their field.

Comment: Isn't every answer an opinion? And if the opinion is shared among large number of people that becomes an answer to that question in that circle. I am not falsely assuming if there is or isn't a clearly defined concept of about anything, not just life. Everything is clearly defined if it makes sense to comprehensive mind, weather that definition is true or not in the real world. Defining something clearly and stating a fact are two different things, isn't it. Wish we had followed on writing an answer, lol :)

Comment: Just to add to the conversation, I find the amalgamation of phiolosophy of life and maths in G.H Hardy's "A Mathematician's Apology". And, the answers are in continuum of the imagination not on the discrete elements of classifiable objects.

Answer (score 3):

They ask different questions. Philosophy may ask what is life, is there a purpose behind it, etc. Biology asks how does it work, chemistry what are the chemical reactions that drive it, physics maybe how does physics allow for life and how life utilizes and impacts physics, and mathematics how can life and its components be described mathematically.

It is good to remember that all scientific disciplines branched off from philosophy (and religious philosophy) and that they are interconnected.

This is the answer to the part of your question that includes biology. If you want to discuss the meaning of life philosophically, you are welcome to come to do it on the philosophy page!

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference along the lines of philosophy vs. science. However, there are broader and narrower definitions in biology.

The broadest I know of is "a self-replicating, chemical system (thing) with both exhibits heredity and some form of homeostasis (display internal negative entropy)", and some even argue the last part may be optional.

The narrowest also requires being made of cells, displaying growth, metabolism, adaptation, and response to stimuli. Some argue against these because they are either implicit in the other definition (homeostasis requires a metabolism, self-replication + heredity = adaptation),  that they are unnecessary (cells or growth) or difficult to define themselves (response to stimuli).